# Are all similar Hermitian matrices unitarily similar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, unitary-matrices, hermitian-matrices, similar-matrices

I wasn't $100\%$ sure in the accuracy of what I obtained, so may I ask for verification?

---

Let $A,B\in M_n(\Bbb C)$ be two similar Hermitian matrices. Then $A=P^{-1}BP$.

According to the spectral theorem, every Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable, so
$A=U_1^{-1}DU_1$ and $B=U_2^{-1}DU_2$, where $U_1,U_2\in M_n(\Bbb C)$ are unitary and $D=\left(\delta_{ij}\right)\in M_n(\Bbb C)$ is diagonal s. t. $\delta_{ii}\in\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are unitarily similar to $D$, I wanted to write $A$ in the following form:
$$A=P^{-1}U_2^{-1}DU_2P$$
Then $U_2P=U_1\implies P=U_2^{-1}U_1$. Since both $U_1$ and $U_2^{-1}$ are unitary, $P$, as a product of two unitary matrices, is also unitary.

**Question** according to this result:

> Are all **similar** Hermitian matrices **unitarily similar**?

If this is valid, can it be used in the proof that the matrix representation of a Hermitian operator in an **orthonormal** basis is a Hermitian matrix? The statement is obvious when, given an arbitrary Hermitian matrix, one is asked to diagonalize it. I thought $P$ could be the transition matrix from one orthonormal basis to another one.

---

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am having a hard time following what you are saying.  It is true that every Hermitian matrix is unitarily equivalent to a diagonal matrix.  But two diagonal matrices are unitarily equivalent if and only if they have the same diagonal elements, up to writing them in a different order.  So the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are 1, 1, and 2 is not unitarily similar to the diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are 2, 2, and 1.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, I didn't mean unitarily _equivalent_, but unitarily _similar_. I'm wondering if Hermitian matrices _are similar_, are they unitarily similar? Let's say we take your example of a diagonal matrix with entries $\operatorname{diag}\{1,1,2\}$. Then, I mean, $A$ is unitarily similar to $D$ and $B$ is unitarily similar to $D$. Then, my problem boils to the possible transitivity of the relation "being unitarily similar". I hope it sounds less messy. We used the term equivalent only for the matrices of the same type and rank to distinguish the _similarity_.

Comment: Sorry.  I thought that similar and equivalent meant the same thing in this context.

Comment: Anyway, is your question this?  "If two Hermitian matrices are similar, then they are unitarily similar?"  If that is the question, then the answer is "yes."

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, thank you for verifying! And more importantly, for the patience!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As verifed by @StephenMontgomery-Smith, all similar Hermitian matrices are unitarily similar, indeed.

Howerver, $P$ doesn't necessarily have to be unitary if, e. g., $A=B=0$. Then every invertible $P$ would suffice.

---

You may see this [parallel question](https://www.quora.com/Are-all-similar-Hermitian-matrices-unitarily-similar-i-e-if-A-B-in-M_n-Bbb-C-are-Hermitian-s-t-A-P-1-BP-is-P-always-unitary-since-they-are-both-unitarily-similar-to-a-Hermitian-diagonal-matrix-I-included-my-work-in?ch=10&share=58b158b7&srid=5D37D) I posted on Quora, answered yesterday by [Aaron Dunbrack](https://www.quora.com/profile/Aaron-Dunbrack-1?ch=10&share=da532569&srid=5D37D).